# What does ranges::starts_with do with C-style string argument(s)?

Tags: c++, string, substring, c-strings, range-v3

The following code prints `1010`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/algorithm/starts_with.hpp>

int main () {
    using namespace std::literals;
    std::cout << ranges::starts_with("hello world"s, "hello"s)
              << ranges::starts_with("hello world"s, "hello")
              << ranges::starts_with("hello world",  "hello"s)
              << ranges::starts_with("hello world",  "hello") << std::endl; // prints 1010

}
```

Why is that?

I've also noticed that if the two stings are the same, then also the last case returns `1`:

```cpp
    std::cout << ranges::starts_with("hello world"s, "hello world"s)
              << ranges::starts_with("hello world"s, "hello world")
              << ranges::starts_with("hello world",  "hello world"s)
              << ranges::starts_with("hello world",  "hello world") << std::endl; // prints 1011
```

I know that a `std::string`, such as `"bla"s`, is a range, and that a `char[N]` is a range too, given a constant `N`. So I don't see why

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: fyi duplicates online clang and gcc - live - https://godbolt.org/z/17veWocxT

Comment: It probably compares the terminating `\0` too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A string literal like `"hello"` is a `const char[N]` array, where `N` includes space for the null terminator, eg `char[6] = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'}`.

A string literal like `"hello"s` is a `std::string` object, which does not include the null terminator in its `size()`.

So, you end up with:

```
starts_with("hello world"s, "hello"s) = 1
// {'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d'}
// DOES begin with
// {'h','e','l','l','o'}

starts_with("hello world"s, "hello") = 0
// {'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d'}
// DOES NOT begin with
// {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'}

starts_with("hello world",  "hello"s) = 1
// {'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d','\0'}
// DOES begin with
// {'h','e','l','l','o'}

starts_with("hello world",  "hello") = 0
// {'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d','\0'}
// DOES NOT begin with
// {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'}

starts_with("hello world"s, "hello world"s) = 1
// {'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d'}
// DOES begin with
// {'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d'}

starts_with("hello world"s, "hello world") = 0
// {'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d'}
// DOES NOT begin with
// {'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d','\0'}

starts_with("hello world",  "hello world"s) = 1
// {'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d','\0'}
// DOES begin with
// {'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d'}

starts_with("hello world",  "hello world") = 1
// {'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d','\0'}
// DOES begin with
// {'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d','\0'}
```